# Monit - issue configuring "check program"

Tags: monit

I'm trying to configure Monit to run my script but it's not working.

I'm running Monit 5.3.2 from a Ubuntu 11.2 environment (it's a virtual machine, my machine actually is Windows 7), and for some reason I cannot make the "check program" to work. It always gives the error:
**Warning: Program is not executable: 'scriptPath'.**

Just in case, I tested by copying the example Monit has on the manual (http://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html) and created the script as the manual, as described below:

An example:

```
  check program myscript with path "/usr/local/bin/myscript.sh"
  if status != 0 then alert
```

Sample script for the above example (`/usr/local/bin/myscript.sh`):

```
 #!/bin/bash
 echo test
 exit $?
```

Anyway, even with those instructions, I still receive the same error message: 
 Warning: Program is not executable: `/usr/local/bin/myscript.sh`

I have no idea what can be happening. Any suggestion is very welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message says, your script file is not executable. You need to add the `x` permissions using `chmod`:

```
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/myscript.sh
```

Comment: Hi Mihael, thank you so much! It worked!
As you see, I'm not only new to Monit but also to Linux!